# Quaternions presented in terms of sine and cosine

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling, quaternions

I'm trying to verify and plot some "strange attractors" based on quaternions.  I found a paper ([The Quaternion Phi Spiral Interference Patterns](https://www.academia.edu/35590531/The_Quaternion_Phi_Spiral_Interference_Patterns)) and was trying to verify and understand the thought process, but **I'm having trouble understanding how quaternions can be presented in terms of sine and cosine, can someone explain this a little better**.

I did try and experiment with [plotting quaternions](https://ijk4de.gitlab.io/3d/quatpics/) just to see the different effects it has on objects .

I've also made some plots based on his theories but I'm still unsure about quaternions being presented in terms of sine and cosine, is this his process correct?  [link to the animated images and plots I generated based on his theory](https://ijk4de.gitlab.io/3d/)

**Here's the quote in the paper:**

> " Although the algebraic representation of the quaternion is widely used in modern engineering, the
>           explicit geometrical representation (akin to the complex numbers) is often overlooked.
>           For a normal complex number $z = w + ix = \mu \cos \theta + i \mu \sin \theta$
>           i.e.
>           \begin{align}
>     w &= \mu \cos θ\\
>     x &= \mu \sin θ
>     \end{align}
>           A quaternion can also be presented in terms of sine and cosine functions but in this case the imaginary
>           part is a vector in $x$, $y$ and $z$ and the non-commutative relations between I, j and k give rise to:
>           \begin{align}
>     w &= \mu \cos θ\\
>     x &= \mu \sin θ \cos φ\\
>     y &= \mu \sin θ \sin φ \cos ψ\\
>     z &= \mu \sin θ \sin φ \sin ψ
>     \end{align}
>           Therefore
>           $$
>     q = \mu (\cos θ + \sin θ (i \cos φ +\sin φ (j \cos ψ + k \sin ψ)))"
>     $$

An example image of what is generated.

[image]

Comment: What is the dynamic that you are simulating? In what sense are these pictures attractors, this word implies some sort of convergence to a set?

Comment: @LutzLehmann  I'm going by how the author refers to them in the paper that's why I put them in quotes. 
https://www.academia.edu/35590531/The_Quaternion_Phi_Spiral_Interference_Patterns

Comment: The prosa of that article is mostly crank, demonstrating that apart from knowing some key words the author does not know much on the topics referenced. The curves are constructed by extending the idea of the spiral from polar coordinates in the plane to spherical coordinates in 4D space, and then projected in different ways. There is nothing inherently quaternionic about it. There is not much more about the coordinate representation than presented in the answer below, the complex patterns occur due to the triple product of sines and cosines in the $y$ and $z$ components.

Comment: The only strange attractor that occurs in that paper is the Lorenz attractor in the unsubstantiated claim that one of the spiralic patterns resembles it.

Comment: Note that the actual computation is for still a different coordinate representation $$q(t)=rt\cos(w_1t)+rt\sin(w_1t)[rt\cos(w_2t)\mathfrak{i}+rt\sin(w_2t)(rt\cos(w_3t)\mathfrak{j}+rt\sin(w_3t)\mathfrak{k})].$$ So $x$ grows quadratically in $t$ and $y,z$ grow cubically.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for the info that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to understand the general square root in the quaternions is $bi+cj+dk$ with$$b,\,c,\,d\in\Bbb R,\,b^2+c^2+d^2=1.$$Since $l:=j\cos\psi+k\sin\psi$ is a square root of $-1$ anticommuting with $i$, and$$AB+BA=0\implies(A+B)^2=A^2+B^2,$$the definition $z:=i\cos\phi+l\sin\phi$ obtains$$z^2=-\cos^2\phi-\sin^2\phi=-1,$$so $\mu\cos\theta+z\mu\sin\theta=\mu\exp z\theta$ is isomorphic to the modulus-$|\mu|$ complex number $\mu\exp i\theta$. This argument is a nice motivation for the $2$-angle form of spherical polar coordinates using $\phi,\,\psi$, since we associate elements of $\Bbb R^3$ with the case $\cos\theta=0$.

Comment: What do you mean with "the general square root"? Did you mean to say that all these quaternions are complex units, square roots of $-1$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes. Furthermore, if $z$ is of this form, $\Bbb R[z]$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Yes, that is what being a complex unit means.